# Disappearing Arraylist Values

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am writing a Java program that will take a sentence (or phrase) and translate it into a group of objects that the computer can easily read. I wanted to make a simple word separating program, and then extend it later on.

My code is like this:

```
package Literary;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordParser {

public static String[] getWords(String tempone){
    ArrayList<String> temptwo = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Character> tempthree = new ArrayList();
    for (int tempfour = 0; tempfour == tempone.length() - 1; tempfour++){
        if (tempone.charAt(tempfour) != ' '){
            tempthree.add(tempone.charAt(tempfour));
    } else {
        temptwo.add(getStringRepresentation(tempthree));
        tempthree.clear();
    }
    }
    String[] tempfive = new String[temptwo.size()];
    for (int tempfour  = 0; tempfour == tempfive.length - 1; tempfour++){
        tempfive[tempfour] = temptwo.get(tempfour);
    }
    return tempfive;
    }

    /** Courtesy of Vineet Reynolds on StackExchange.
     * 
     *  "You can iterate through the list and create the string."
     * 
     * @param list
     * @return 
     */

    public static String getStringRepresentation(ArrayList<Character> list){    
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(list.size());
        for(int i = 0; i == list.size() + 1; i++)
        {
            builder.append(list.get(i).charValue());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

It's supposed to receive a string as an input, and return a list of strings that have been separated by spaces.

But when I run my main class:

```
import Literary.WordParser;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "There was once a sword in the stone";
        String[] tempstring = WordParser.getWords(x);
        for (int i = 1; i == tempstring.length; i++){
           System.out.println("Word " + i + " : " + tempstring[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The console tells me nothing except `run:` and `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)`.

I'm using Netbeans 8 and Java 1.7 if that helps.

Comment: Are you using maven? It sounds like you've just built your class, not executed it. What task are you executing?

Comment: No, Netbeans, and I know the main class executed because when I placed another System.out.println outside the for loop, it appeared in the console.

Comment: Question: Why aren't you using a method such as .split(" ") to break up the sentence? Or are you doing this more as an excercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the problem's here:

```
for (int i = 1; i == tempstring.length; i++) {
```

This for loop will run at most once: if `tempstring` is exactly one `String` long, it should print out the word.

However, since your test sentence has 8 words, nothing will ever print out (provided `WordParser` works correctly).

You probably want to change this line to: (note the `<` between `i` and `tempstring.length`.)

```
for (int i = 1; i < tempstring.length; i++) {
```

so that it will loop through all the items in `tempstring`.

Comment: You might want to explain what change he needs to make to get it to work.

Comment: The short version:  The for loop keeps going *while* the test is true, not *until* is is true.

Comment: I didn't even think about the loops. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You had multiple issues in your code:

1) for loops were not properly made, they would never execute. Use either `!=, > or <` instead of `==`.

2) you don't need a method getWords() nor getStringRepresentation(). Method like that are already implemented in Java.

So the final code should be this:

```
public class WordParser {

    public static String[] getWords(String tempone) {
        return tempone.split(" ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "There was once a sword in the stone";
        String[] tempstring = WordParser.getWords(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < tempstring.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Word " + (i+1) + " : " + tempstring[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Word 1 : There
Word 2 : was
Word 3 : once
Word 4 : a
Word 5 : sword
Word 6 : in
Word 7 : the
Word 8 : stone
```

I've also fixed your code that runs the same as above, if you are interested:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class WordParser {

    public static String[] getWords(String tempone) {
        ArrayList<String> sarr = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Character> tempthree = new ArrayList<Character>();
        String[] ansarr;

        if(tempone.charAt(tempone.length()-1) != ' ')
            tempone += " "; //Add white space to the end to catch the last word

        for (int i = 0; i < tempone.length(); i++) {
            if (tempone.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                tempthree.add(tempone.charAt(i));
            } else {
                sarr.add(tempthree.toString());
                tempthree.clear();
            }
        }

        ansarr = new String[sarr.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ansarr.length; i++) {
            ansarr[i] = sarr.get(i);
        }
        return ansarr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "There was once a sword in the stone";
        String[] tempstring = WordParser.getWords(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < tempstring.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Word " + (i+1) + " : " + tempstring[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [`String.split(" ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) which seems to do the same thing

Comment: Yes, but what if OP was doing this for a homework assignment or as an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Change your main method as follows, 
and it will work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "There was once a sword in the stone";
        String[] tempstring = WordParser.getWords(x);
        for (int i = 1; i <= tempstring.length; i++){
           System.out.println("Word " + i + " : " + tempstring[i - 1]);
        }
    }
```

For the WordParser you could use,

```
public class WordParser 
{
    public static String[] getWords(String tempone)
    {
        return tempone.split(" ");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, I would recommend using the split method to break up a sentence
it is defined as:

```
 public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

and you can simply call

```
 String s1=new String("Random words in a sentence");
 String[] words=s1.split(" ");
```

in order to break the string up into words and you will now have a String
array of five elements where each element consists of a word

In Respect to your question, you are not using the conditional statement correctly
You want to iterate over the elements of the String array WHILE the position
is less than stringname.length, not only if it the position equals the stringname.length

Therefore, you must make the following changes in these parts of your code

For Example:

```
  for (int i = 1; i == tempstring.length; i++)
```

should have its line changed to

```
  for (int i = 1; i < tempstring.length; i++)
```

and this problem also occurs in various places in your WordParser.java file
It is useful to remember also that you may often want to start at index 0 instead
of index 1, as java has its' first indice as 0.